# counting unique values in 1 column only if within 7 days of 2nd date column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have this so far

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(B2:B10,B2:B10,0),MATCH(B2:B10,B2:B10,0))>0,1))
```

which counts the unique values in 1 column as long as the cell is not blank.

What I also need to do is only count these unique values if the date in a second column is a date within 7 days of today's date

It needs to be automated. My idea was to incorporate this into a countif/s statement.

Does anyone have some idea's for me?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the countif/s - you'd have to put the condition in before doing the FREQUENCY something like this:-

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF((TODAY()-C2:C10)>7,"",MATCH(B2:B10,B2:B10,0)),IF((TODAY()-C2:C10)>7,"",MATCH(B2:B10,B2:B10,0)))>0,1))
```

and that has to be an array formula entered with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>   <kbd>Shift</kbd>   <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: the code i have already counts unique frequency without errors, what i need to do is add a condition so it only counts if the second column has a date less than 7 days old

Comment: OK I have added a screenshot to show that I get a different count with my formula.